# Outlier detection with non normal distribution

Tags: anomaly-detection

What are some techniques that I can use for anomaly detection given a non-Normal distribution? I have less than twenty available observations.

Comment: Checkout QQ plots also with what JahKnows said..

Comment: @JahKnows - if the offer still stands, I would like to ask for an easy introduction.

Comment: @user7677771, probably best to ask a separate question to avoid reviving old posts. But, sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a nearest neighbors approach. This technique is non-parametric, such that it does not assume your features follow any given distribution. The degree from which a novel instance can be classified as anomalous can set through some p-value estimation. These techniques are computationally expensive however due to your small dataset this may be well suited.

---

**Check out:**

Learning Minimum Volume Sets
http://www.stat.rice.edu/~cscott/pubs/minvol06jmlr.pdf

Anomaly Detection with Score functions based on Nearest Neighbor Graphs
https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5461

New statistic in P-value estimation for anomaly detection
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6319713/

---

You can also use more rudimentary anomaly detection techniques such as a generalized likelihood ratio test. But, this is kind of old-school.

Comment: I can elaborate on how these techniques work if you have difficulty with the paper. They're relatively easy concepts clouded in a lot of theory in the papers.

Comment: Does this approach work with non-negative distributions as well?